# nginx rewrite folder http to https

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I currently have 2 server containers, 1 for http, and another for the same server but https. I want to merge those containers using `Listen 80;` and `Listen 443 ssl;`, which works but I need to rewrite a URL different now:

```
    location ^~ /wp-admin {
            rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ^~ /wp-login.php {
            rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

When HTTP and HTTPS are combined, this leads to an infinite location loop. I need to change the pattern but I don't get it to work:

```
    location ~ ^http://domain\.com/wp-admin {
            rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ~ ^http://domain\.com/wp-login.php {
            rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

This does not work, anyone knows?

Comment: Don't do this. You should keep the `server` blocks separated.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This sir, is the most reasonable approach; I'm going to keep the containers seperated.

Comment: Also, you might use if ($server_port = 80) or 443 around your rewrite conditional (under the "location").

Comment: @D.Kasipovic If you provide this as an answer using my config lines, I will accept it, tho I gone with Michael's advice.

Comment: If you are not going to use it, and do not need it, then never mind. If you need it as an example, I will provide it.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic I don't know, my question is obsolete now, should I delete it? If not, and you provide an answer it might help others. I don't mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Hampton said, this is best accomplished using separate server {} blocks for ports 80 and 443.

Another solution is something like this:

```
location ^~ /wp-admin {
  if ($server_port = 80) {
    rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
```